# Ruby on Rails undefined local variable or method

Tags: variables, ruby-on-rails-4, undefined, local, redirecttoroute

I'm having a problem with redirecting my website to a different page, if the person is younger then a certain age. Either, I need more coffee or I've lost it, I can't seem to see what I did wrong. Thanks so much.

**app/models/student.rb**

## Im trying to sent people to a different site with redirect

```
 private
  def must_be_over_13
    if birthday && birthday > 13.years.ago
      redirect_to under_13_landing_page_path ``
    end
  end
```

## I defined under_13_landing_page

**controller/student controller**

```
 def under_13_landing_page
  end
```

**views/students**

## I made the redirect page

```
under_13_landing_page.html
```

**config/routes.rb**

## I told it to redirect it to the landing page

```
get "games_for_kids", to: "students#under_13_landing_page", as: 'under_13_landing_page'
```

THE ERROR**undefined local variable or method `under_13_landing_page_path' for #**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rendering` and `redirection` are *Controller's* responsibility NOT *Model's*. You should not be redirecting in the *Model* `app/models/student.rb`. This is the reason of the code failure as Model doesn't have access to the route helper methods such as `under_13_landing_page_path` in your case.

I would suggest you to return a `boolean` value from `Student#must_be_over_13`  method which you can then check in the concerned controller and `redirect` appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your fast and well detailed response. That makes total sense!